# How to check if valid extension for all type of excel extensions

Tags: javascript, excel

I have an input field to allow all type of excel extensions like this:

```
<input name="file" type="file" id="inputGroupFile01" accept=".xl*">
```

But to make sure the user did not upload something else I have a javascript function which gets called whenever a file is uploaded, before it is sent to the database.

It goes something like this:

```
var fileType = $('#inputGroupFile01').val().split('.').pop();
if (fileType != 'xls'){
 *error msg*
}
```

This works well for xls file but not for others. And this

```
if (fileType != 'xl*')
```

obviously did not work.

Is there a way to do this without writing all xl types in the if statement.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This works well for xls file *but not for others.* what other files do you want to support here?

Comment: All excel file types like: XLSX, XLSM, XLTX, XLTM, etc

Comment: I'm doing that for now, but I wanted to know if there is a more general way of doing this rather than writing 6-7 `||` statements in if condition. Like i did it in the input `accept = '.xl*'`

Comment: Just realised I can use regular expression for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `xl*` you can use `string.startWith()` function,

```
var fileType = $('#inputGroupFile01').val().split('.').pop();
if (!filetype.startsWith("xl")){
 *error msg*
}
```

```js
var xls = "xls";
var txt = "txt";

if(xls.startsWith(xls))
  console.log("xls : excel extension");
  
  
if(!txt.startsWith(xls))
  console.log("txt : not excel extension");
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.